Priority Issues - Use LEX to write regular expressions to match strings of specific patterns
I try to write regular definitions to display the line of string for the following
using LEX.
a.Match any string starting with d, and ending with t
b. Matches the string def
c.Match one or more occurrences ab concatenated
d. Match any string of one or more characters that do not include upper
case A-Z
I don't know why the program got an unexpected result. And the program couldn't stop.
Below is my C code:
%{
    #include <stdio.h>
%}

%%

def {
    printf("Matched 'def' string: %s\n", yytext);
}

d.*t {
    printf("Matched 'd...t' string: %s\n", yytext);
}

(ab)+ {
    printf("Matched 'ab' concatenated: %s\n", yytext);
}

[^A-Z]+ {
    printf("Matched string (no uppercase A-Z): %s\n", yytext);
}

%%

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    printf("\nEnter the string:\n");
    yylex();  // Start lexical analysis
    return 0;
}

int yywrap(){
    return 1;
}

The below picture is my output. I don't know why the program got an unexpected result. And the program couldn't stop.
PS C:\CODE\CST302-Compiler-Principles\Lab3\Q2> flex Q2.l
PS C:\CODE\CST302-Compiler-Principles\Lab3\Q2> g++ lex.yy.c
PS C:\CODE\CST302-Compiler-Principles\Lab3\Q2> ./a

Enter the string:
dooot def abc abab ABCd
Matched string (no uppercase A-Z): dooot def abc abab
ABC

abc


I can't reproduce the `
abc` at the end of your post.

I press 'enter' twice but can't exit the input mode. Then I type 'abc' to show it.

The problem is that lex is greedy and tries to get the longest sequence of characters. The sequence dooot def abc abab  is 19 characters long, so it will be the selected sequence. That mean that you cannot use a pattern that eats all characters until another matched pattern, but process those characters one at a time.
Here I would use a global condition to know whether we are already gathering ^A-Z characters. Then I would print the message when entering the condition, and print the end of line when another pattern is selected.
For the program couldn't stop problem, it is in fact a lex feature: it reads its standard input until an end of file condition (or an explicit return). If you want to process one single line, you should detect the end of line character and put an explicit return in its action.
Here is a possible lex file:
%{
    #include <stdio.h>
    int in_upper = 0;
    void end_upper() {
        if (in_upper) {
            in_upper = 0;
            fputc('\n', stdout);
        }
    }
%}

%%

def {
    end_upper();
    printf("Matched 'def' string: %s\n", yytext);
}

d.*t {
    end_upper();
    printf("Matched 'd...t' string: %s\n", yytext);
}

(ab)+ {
    end_upper();
    printf("Matched 'ab' concatenated: %s\n", yytext);
}

\n {
    // explicitely returns at the first end of line
    end_upper();
    return 0;
}

[^A-Z] {
    if (! in_upper) {
        printf("Matched string (no uppercase A-Z): ");
        in_upper = 1;
    }
    printf("%s", yytext);
}

. {
    // explicitly ignore A-Z characters to be able to call end_upper if appropriate
    end_upper();
}
%%

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    printf("\nEnter the string:\n");
    yylex();  // Start lexical analysis
    return 0;
}

int yywrap(){
    return 1;
}

